# Examples of ineffective PH collapse theorems?

Tags: big-list, polynomial-hierarchy

What are some examples of theorems of the form "If $X$, then $PH$ collapses", but where the proof does not say which level $PH$ collapses to?

The canonical example would be "If $PH = PSPACE$, then $PH$ collapses", though this one is trivial.  Are there more interesting examples?

Comment: I think your last example has little to do with PSPACE being an "adaptive union of the levels of PH": the same holds for any class C which has a complete problem and contains PH (and just assuming C in PH, but I think that's what you meant anyway).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow: Yep, that's fair.

Comment: Your example does not fit the criterion, it seems. If P=PSPACE then PH collapses to its 0th level.

Comment: @RyanWilliams: I think he meant if PSPACE is in PH (then we know it collapses, but not to which level).

Comment: It's easy to construct trivial examples. One that's probably not obvious (without knowing Toda's theorem) is that $\mathrm{PP} \subseteq \mathrm{PH}$ implies the collapse of $\mathrm{PH}$. But this is only "technically" true, as knowing where in the hierarchy $\mathrm{PP}$ lies will give you a pretty good estimate for where $\mathrm{PH}$ collapses.

Comment: Yep, I meant $PH = PSPACE$.  Fixed.